# when it is possible that if you interchange the lines of adding a and b, then hashSet.size () == 2 instead of 3:

Tags: java, transitive-dependency

When it is possible that if you interchange the lines of adding a and b, then

```
hashSet.size () == 2 instead of 3:
a = ;  
b = ;  
c = ;
Set <ThirdPartyType> hashSet = new ...;
hashSet.add (a); hashSet.add (b); hashSet.add (c);
```

Comment: When you haven't implemented `hashCode`/`equals` correctly.

Comment: Set doesn't allow duplicate values and the detection of duplication depends on `hashcode/equals` implementation. You must be adding three items but out of three two are same and hence the final size seems to be 2.

Comment: You should provide the `hashCode` and `equals` implementation of the `ThirdPartyType`. This is where the problem is. If you haven't implemented them, this is also where the problem is.